# Not possible to write a Debug Visualizer for Silverlight 4?

Tags: silverlight

Is it true that it's just not possible to write a debug visualizer for Silverlight 4?  I'm guessing not, as the [Serializable] attribute doesn't seem to even be available.

Comment: What is a "debug visualizer"?

Comment: @AnthonyWJones - See [this link.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zayyhzts.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know that you cannot write a debug visualizer for Silverlight 4, but I'm not exactly sure why. [Josh Smith](http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2011/02/22/mole-2010-has-shipped/) says as much in reference to Mole 2010 (see the first couple of comments).

I do know that you cannot display Silverlight controls on the design surface of the XAML design view, which is probably related.